# What is the modern use of $\bigodot$ sign?

Tags: geometry, matrices, notation

I've seen $\bigodot$ used in various contexts. It's used for a special set theory operation by some authors (say, Saks) and as sign for Hadamard product by a couple other authors (say, Wiener) in the past ... pre-1950. Now Hadamard product has a different sign as standard, so what is this used for now?

EDIT: I confirm a single use in Blackadar's 2006 Operator Algebras but that is about it.

Comment: For example for algebraic tensor products of $C^*$ algebras. See Bruce Blacadar's monograph

Comment: An arrow pointing towards you.

Comment: In cosmology the symbol is commonly used to denote the sun. Used as a subscript to indicate solar mass or solar radius for example.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the cosmology usage, but I was wondering if the symbol is still used in a standard way in mathematics. Some form of tensor product? But there I've seen only modified tensor product symbol used. BTW, Norbert, you mean Blackadar's Operator Algebras book?

Comment: Laurent Schwartz used it  for the symmetric algebra  of a vector space $V$, so that you have the harmonious sequence $\otimes V, \wedge  V,  \bigodot V$ .

Comment: @Georges: Interesting!